# How to update Laravel to latest minor?

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I've started only recently working on Laravel.

I've only few 'pages' (routes+views and a single model) until now.

If I check artisan version I got

```
php artisan --version
Laravel Framework 5.4.19
```

I'd like to update ALL to 5.4.23, to keep FW and vendor packages updated.

What's the rigt procedure?

I started the project using `laravel new <project-name>`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Simply run `composer update`

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 0 installs, 15 updates, 0 removals
  - Updating symfony/css-selector (v3.2.7 => v3.2.8): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating symfony/var-dumper (v3.2.7 => v3.2.8): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating symfony/routing (v3.2.7 => v3.2.8): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating symfony/process (v3.2.7 => v3.2.8): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating symfony/http-foundation (v3.2.7 => v3.2.8): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating symfony/event-dispatcher (v3.2.7 => v3.2.8): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating symfony/debug (v3.2.7 => v3.2.8): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating symfony/http-kernel (v3.2.7 => v3.2.8): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating symfony/finder (v3.2.7 => v3.2.8): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating symfony/console (v3.2.7 => v3.2.8): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating swiftmailer/swiftmailer (v5.4.7 => v5.4.8): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating symfony/translation (v3.2.7 => v3.2.8): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating league/flysystem (1.0.39 => 1.0.40): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating laravel/framework (v5.4.19 => v5.4.23): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating symfony/yaml (v3.2.7 => v3.2.8): Downloading (100%)
```